# Options to maintain line breaks in PHP > HTML source code?

Tags: php, html

I'd like to keep my HTML source code pretty and indented (or tabbed). For instance:

```
$someHTML.='<div class="NOINDENT">';
$someHTML.='    <div class="INDENT1">';
$someHTML.='        <div class="INDENT2"><div>';
$someHTML.='    </div>';
$someHTML.='</div>';

echo $someHTML;
```

This PHP looks pretty and readable enough to me, but when the HTML is output it will be one long line of code (with no line breaks)! I'd like to have PHP print a line break, but still have the code "readable" while working on it in PHP.

For the above example, is using \n at the end of each line my only option?

Comment: by the way, people do usually the opposite: trying to remove all invisible character (like new lines and tabs) in order to make their page lighter

Comment: @Asenar Yes I understand, that's called minify correct? I will be minifying other things like the CSS and possibly Javascript, but I would like the HTML to look as natural as possible (although I can't think of a good reason other than aesthetics).

Comment: yes for the name :) . That's my opinion, but I suggest you to focus on the look of your .php files, where you read it/change it often, more than the html output, where you will almost never look at it (in particular if your sources are clean). Of course the best solution would be to have an architecture which allows you to separate the "views" and "controller" code, or using a template engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the constant `PHP_EOL` to end your lines

```
$someHTML.='<div class="NOINDENT">'.PHP_EOL;
```

The HEREDOC syntax is better, but when you are inside functions / loop / etc. which requires tabs, it make the php code looks weird sometimes

Comment: I kind of liek this better than using \n

Answer (score 3):

[Heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to the rescue

```
$someHTML = <<<HTML
<div>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

I try and avoid echoing html if its more than a single line.

Instead you can use output buffering if you need the html in a string, eg if you need to return a string from a function:

```
function getHtmlString(){
    ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="NOINDENT">
        <div class="INDENT1">
            <div class="INDENT2"><div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}
?>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <div id="someid">
        <?php echo getHtmlString(); ?>
    ...
```

Comment: easier to just use a heredoc. no need to get the buffering system involved.

Comment: True in this specific case, but not so when logic blocks are required, as might appear in a full template

Comment: Trying to stay away from this , all the <?php and ?> can get too messy for my liking, even thought this is how I did it for years. However, the great advantage of using this way were that the HTML can be seen in something like Dreamweaver.

Comment: @unclepete personal choice i suppose, but i find doing the above, along with using templating php syntax eg `foreach(..): endforeach;` massivly more readable than echoing escaped html. Plus as you mention, it works a lot better with IDE's, so you can collopse sections, get syntax highlighting etc. Javascript is another plus - echoing escaped javascript is not fun

Comment: Great points user574632, I actually use a mix of the two (my example and yours). The reason I use the way in my example, is one long HTML "string" can be returned in a function. Not sure how HTML can be return()ed using this method.

Comment: @unclepete thats what output buffering is for, i have updated my answer with a fuller example

Comment: @user574632 Your answer works great, and my last comment regarding returning the HTML was my oversite, yours is a great solution. However I am trying to stay away from using  <?php as part of the solution, in my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must add '\n' at the end.

And if you want tabs, add '\t' at the beggining of each line.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use line breaks, you need to use the double-quoted string form and place a newline (`\n`) character at the end of every line. Note that the double quotes *within* the string now need to be escaped with a backslash. For example:

```
$someHTML.="<div class=\"NOINDENT\">\n";
$someHTML.="    <div class=\"INDENT1\">\n";
$someHTML.="        <div class=\"INDENT2\"><div>\n";
$someHTML.="    </div>\n";
$someHTML.="</div>\n";

echo $someHTML;
```

Another option would be to use the [HEREDOC string format](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which will maintain whitespace and also has the advantage of not requiring you to escape double quotes:

```
$someHTML = <<<HERE
<div class="NOINDENT">
    <div class="INDENT1">
        <div class="INDENT2"><div>
    </div>
</div>
HERE;
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew for this concise answer. I would like to vote this up but am 2 shy of that privelege.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show that this solution is close to what I want , and works great, but the staring and ending ' and '; aren't that pretty. heredoc seems like the best and cleanest answer so far.

```
function html(){
    $someHTML=
'<div class="NOINDENT">a
    <div class="INDENT1">b
        <div class="INDENT2">c<div>
    </div>
</div>';
    return $someHTML;
}

echo(html());
```